# Calling s.tl throws a TypeError

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I'm having a problem with Omniture that happens if I set s.products to something akin to

```
s.products = ";101;;;;eVar33=mystatus";
```

Unfortunately when the script later calls `s.tl`, it crashes. The error has the following description in Firefox:

> TypeError: tl is not a function

When I put in a product like usual, with only the product `s.tl` works:

```
s.products = ";101";
```

Anyone knows why the script may crash like this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're going to have to provide some more context.  More code, link to where the issue is, something.  I tried the following test code:

```
<a href='#' onclick="s_dlt(this);">click</a>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="omniture.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"><!--

function s_dlt(that) {
  var s=s_gi(s_account);
  s.linkTrackVars='products';
  s.products = ";101;;;;eVar33=mystatus";
  s.tl(that,'d','some name');
}   
/************* DO NOT ALTER ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE ! **************/
var s_code=s.t();if(s_code)document.write(s_code)//--></script>
```

and I see products being sent in request just fine, no .js errors or nothin'.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. I accidentally reassigned the s variable elsewhere in the code. Thanks for the help.